# Combining PDFs with digital signatures

Tags: php, linux, pdf

I am having an issue combining PDFs with digital signatures.  I've tried everything from pdftk to ghostscript with no success.  Using ghostscript it will process every page except for those with the signatures.  Here is the command I'm using

```
exec('gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile='.$new_file.' -c .setpdfwrite -f '.$doc_list.' 2>&1', $output);
```

I don't think the ghostscript will achieve what I am trying to do so my question is, is there any option for doing this? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at mPDF? http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Comment: You do realize that there is no way to do this while keeping the signatures valid, right?

Comment: I'm not concerned with keeping the signatures, they are getting printed once merged